# Full-screen, Full screen or Fullscreen

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

What difference is there between:

- **Full-screen**
- **Full screen**
- **Fullscreen**

Which of these terms means "*click to switch to full-screen mode*"?

I was guessing that **full-screen** is an *adjective*, and **fullscreen** is a misprint for **full screen**, but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: "Press.to enter full-screen mode"--shouldn't it be "click _to switch to_ full-screen mode"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct would be

> **full-screen**

since it is a compound adjective in

> **full-screen** mode

however

> full screen
>   fullscreen

would still be understood, especially given how words are concatenated these days under the influence of programming with [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) and [CamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case)

Comment: **full-screen** is only an adjective, right? Whereas **full screen** is a noun?

Answer (score 2):

'**fullscreen**' is now taking a trend and is becoming a new norm due to the popular concatenation of the phrase '**full screen**'. I have seen the phrase said as '**fullscreen**' in many places, but it is mostly an informal spelling. You may see in formal documents that the phrase '**full screen**' is used (but do note that said documents are sometimes quite old, before the phrase's mainstream usage in places such as online media streaming).

Answer (score 1):

- The presentation template occupied the full screen. (complete screen is better
  though)
- Full screen was wiped down.
- Full-screen presentation mode.

Usage is still full screen with space across various content. The very recent content in the last 2 decades has started using fullscreen without space. Of course, it means that the word without space is well understood and accepted. It is still used in most written content with a space. A good sample is via [Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=fullscreen%2C%20full-screen%2C%20full%20screen&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfullscreen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfull%20-%20screen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfull%20screen%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cfullscreen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfull%20-%20screen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfull%20screen%3B%2Cc0).